# Compiling gcc 4.7 on windows

Tags: c++, gcc

I've found I think very good tutorial on how to compile gcc on windows http://www.aristeia.com/Misc/gcc4ForWindows.html#buildinggcc
but I'm stuck on the (surprise, surprise) main point of it, which is building actual gcc. Just to make your life easier, I'm struck here:

```
configuring:
   # ../../source/gcc-4.1.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32
   --target=mingw32 --program-prefix="" --with-as=/mingw/bin/as.exe
   --with-ld=/mingw/bin/ld.exe --with-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as
   --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-languages=c,c++
   --disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --without-x --enable-interpreter
   --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
```

The problem is that nothing's happening after I type this, so obviously I must have done something wrong. Any ideas?

Edit, that is my folders' structure:

```
/gcc-work/source/gcc
$ ls
ABOUT-NLS           boehm-gc      depcomp    libjava       lto-plugin
COPYING             config        include    libmudflap    lt~obsolete.m4
COPYING.RUNTIME     config-ml.in  intl       libquadmath   move-if-change
ChangeLog           config.rpath  libgomp    libstdc++-v3  zlib
ChangeLog.tree-ssa  configure.ac  libiberty  libtool.m4
Makefile.in         contrib       libitm     ltmain.sh
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If compiling a GCC **4.7** (which has not yet being released!) you probably don't have `source/gcc-4.1.1/configure` which suggest a path for a GCC 4.1.1. So put the right path (to the topmost `configure` of your GCC source tree).

Comment: Hi, thanks, I've changed that already ;) to no avail, unfortunately.

Comment: That's what I'm sending as a command:  $  ../../source/gcc/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --target=mingw32 -
-program-prefix="" --with-as=/mingw/bin/as.exe --with-ld=/mingw/bin/ld.exe --wi
th-gcc --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --enable-threads --disable-nls --enable-lang
uages=c,c++ -disable-win32-registry --disable-shared --without-x --enable-inter
preter --enable-hash-synchronization --enable-libstdcxx-debug
sh: ../../source/gcc/configure: No such file or directory

Comment: Try putting an absolute path for `configure` and check that it is right.

Comment: Basil would you like to tell me how to do it (how to put an absolute path)?

Comment: I mean a path starting with / e.g. `/home/foo/bar/gcc-trunk/configure` ; however, if you are already stuck by that, chances are you'll take a lot of your time to compile GCC. (for example, what about PPL & Cloog support, these are libraries useful to GCC)?

Comment: Basil, I didn't see anything in this tutorial about those libraries mentioned by you.

Comment: Basil, here is a wild thought: how about you and me in chat room, step by step do it and after that either I or you post cleared steps in here as a tutorial for others?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you. I know nothing about Windows. I'm only using Linux. And a GCC on Linux gives you more than a GCC on Windows (for instance plugins are not supported on Windows GCC).

Comment: ok, fair enough, what about me installing linux and then asking you for a help with compiling gcc on it?

Answer (score 7):

Honestly, if I were you I wouldn't go through all that headache!

The most up to date website that offers Mingw with latest gcc version I have found is: http://www.equation.com. Go to their [programming tools page](http://www.equation.com/servlet/equation.cmd?fa=fortran), and grab the latest version of gcc. They offer both the latest weekly snapshot and the latest official version.

Comment: Now they require username and password! Any other alternative solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `#` sign is supposed to represent your [root prompt](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_Unix/Explanations/Shell_Prompt#Root_shell_prompt) and should not be typed.

If you add it to your command line, nothing will happen since it's also the shell's comment delimiter.

Comment: nope, I've must done something wrong. Now I'm getting an error telling me ../../gcc/configure no such file or directory

Comment: According to the article you linked to, your current directory should be `/gcc-work/build/gcc`. Is that the case?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I was in the source directory. I'm gonna change it and try it again.

Comment: No, I'm still getting the same: no such file or directory error

Comment: Maybe the script location has changed between gcc 4.1 and 4.7. In the top of the source tree, there should be two files named `README` and `INSTALL`. Considering reading them, they should contain the location of the `configure` script.

Comment: Frederic, there are no such files (README nor INSTALL)?